# Add a request form button to SharePoint 2016 calendar

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-calendar

I am new to SharePoint. I added a calendar web part to a SharePoint page so we can add events to it. I've given read access permissions to the calendar to users external to our organization. I want to create a link or button on the page so that the external users can request to add an event to our calendar so it can be reviewed by our team before being added to the calendar. What is the approach I should take for this? Is there a specific web part I should add to page for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give edit permission to external users,so they could add events.And you should activate the content approval in list version setting.
[image]

The events added by others will not show until approved by who has approve permission.

More reference about sharepoint permission:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Amos_MSFT. Would that require content approval even for our internal users?

Comment: Yes,but you could  a permission which contains approval permission to internal users,then they could approve their events by themselves.Or you could custom a permission level.